# How to solve "ValueError: Unable to unpack value [] as a tf.compat.v1.GraphDef"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'm following the tutorial of TensorFlow_Federated: custom_federated_algorithms_2. Everything works when I just copy and run the tutorial's code. So I wanna change the code by myself for being more familar with tff. Then bug appeared.

My runtime environment:

python: `3.8.12`

tensorflow: `2.5.0`

tensorflow_federated: `0.19.0`

Code below is the orginal code of testing model in tutorial:

```py
MODEL_SPEC = collections.OrderedDict(
    weights=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[784, 10], dtype=tf.float32),
    bias=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[10], dtype=tf.float32))
MODEL_TYPE = tff.to_type(MODEL_SPEC)
print(MODEL_TYPE) # <weights=float32[784,10],bias=float32[10]>


BATCH_SPEC = collections.OrderedDict(
    x=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 784], dtype=tf.float32),
    y=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)
)
BATCH_TYPE = tff.to_type(BATCH_SPEC)
print(BATCH_TYPE) # <x=float32[?,784],y=int32[?]>
```

And I changed the `MODEL_TYPE` into:

```py
MODEL_SPEC = collections.OrderedDict(
    fc1=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[784, 256], dtype=tf.float32),
    b1=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32),
    fc2=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[256, 128], dtype=tf.float32),
    b2=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[128], dtype=tf.float32),
    fc3=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[128, 10], dtype=tf.float32),
    b3=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[10], dtype=tf.float32)
)
MODEL_TYPE = tff.to_type(MODEL_SPEC)
```

Thanks to the structure of model changed, the process of forward pass needs to be changed too:

```py
# original
@tf.function
def forward_pass(model, batch):
  predicted_y = tf.nn.softmax(
      tf.matmul(batch['x'], model['weights']) + model['bias'])
  return -tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.reduce_sum(
          tf.one_hot(batch['y'], 10) * tf.math.log(predicted_y), axis=[1]))

@tff.tf_computation(MODEL_TYPE, BATCH_TYPE)
def batch_loss(model, batch):
  return forward_pass(model, batch)

# new 
@tf.function
def forward(model, batch):
    logits = batch["x"] @ model["fc1"] + model["b1"]

    logits = logits @ model["fc2"] + model["b2"]

    logits = logits @ model["fc3"] + model["b3"]

    logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=-1,)
    
    one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(batch["y"], depth=10)
    return -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.log(logits) * one_hot_y, axis=[1]))


@tff.tf_computation(MODEL_TYPE, BATCH_TYPE)
def batch_loss(model, batch):
    return forward(model, batch)
```

I didn't change the `batch_train()` code.

```py
@tff.tf_computation(MODEL_TYPE, BATCH_TYPE, tf.float32)
def batch_train(initial_model, batch, learning_rate):
  # Define a group of model variables and set them to `initial_model`. Must
  # be defined outside the @tf.function.
  model_vars = collections.OrderedDict([
      (name, tf.Variable(name=name, initial_value=value))
      for name, value in initial_model.items()
  ])
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

  @tf.function
  def _train_on_batch(model_vars, batch):
    # Perform one step of gradient descent using loss from `batch_loss`.
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      loss = forward_pass(model_vars, batch)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model_vars)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(tf.nest.flatten(grads), tf.nest.flatten(model_vars)))
    return model_vars

  return _train_on_batch(model_vars, batch)
```

And it works fine so far. But when implementing the `local_train()` section, errors appeared even I just using the original code.

```py
initial_model = collections.OrderedDict(
    fc1=tf.zeros([784, 256]),
    b1=tf.zeros([256]),
    fc2=tf.zeros([256,128]),
    b2=tf.zeros([128]),
    fc3=tf.zeros([128, 10]),
    b3=tf.zeros([10])
)
LOCAL_DATA_TYPE = tff.SequenceType(BATCH_TYPE)

@tff.federated_computation(MODEL_TYPE, tf.float32, LOCAL_DATA_TYPE)
def local_train(initial_model, learning_rate, all_batches):

  @tff.tf_computation(LOCAL_DATA_TYPE, tf.float32)
  def _insert_learning_rate_to_sequence(dataset, learning_rate):
    return dataset.map(lambda x: (x, learning_rate))

  batches_with_learning_rate = _insert_learning_rate_to_sequence(all_batches, learning_rate)

  # Mapping function to apply to each batch.
  @tff.federated_computation(MODEL_TYPE, batches_with_learning_rate.type_signature.element)
  def batch_fn(model, batch_with_lr):
    batch, lr = batch_with_lr
    return batch_train(model, batch, lr)

  return tff.sequence_reduce(batches_with_learning_rate, initial_model, batch_fn)

locally_trained_model = local_train(initial_model, 1e-1, mnist_train_dataset[5])
# ValueError: Unable to unpack value [] as a tf.compat.v1.GraphDef
```

Comment: Welcome! Trying to simplify the code to a minimal example which fails would increase chance someone will find what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that I had made a low-level mistake.‍♂️
Which is I coded on my custom jupyter notebook, but forgot to add the following key code in the tutorial at the begining:

```
executor_factory = tff.framework.local_executor_factory(
    support_sequence_ops=True

)
execution_context = tff.framework.ExecutionContext(
    executor_fn=executor_factory
)
tff.framework.set_default_context(execution_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I noticed on a quick skim (did not sift through all of the pasted code) is this line:

```
  return batch_train(model, batch, lr)
```

To invoke a `tff.tf_computation` from within the context of a `tff.federated_computation`, you need to use the `tff.federated_map` operator. So it could look like

```
  return tff.federated_map(batch_train, (model, batch, lr))
```

Comment: Thank for answering. By following your suggestion, it actually raises another error: `TypeError: The value to be mapped must be a FederatedType or implicitly convertible to a FederatedType ` And so far, the tutorial has not been pushed to the federated situation, so `(model, batch, lr)` isn't a `FederatedType` value.

Comment: And weirdly, I had tried to paste my custom code into the official jupyter notebook of this tutorial then run. Suprisingly, it can calculate the local loss successfully, and the loss keep decreasing while training.